how do i enable showing the pop up for App Traking transparnecy permission in ios app using cordova
"I uploaded my iOS app to the App Store, but it got suspended with a message stating, 'We are looking forward to completing our review, but we need more information to continue. Your app uses the App Tracking Transparency framework, but we are unable to locate the app tracking transparency permission request when reviewed on iOS 14.7.1."
"I've thoroughly researched across different platforms and installed all available plugins provided by Cordova. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to my issue. Could someone please offer guidance or suggestions on how to address this?"

post your config.xml
